# Why I get Cannot set property 'na0' of undefined error?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var places = { };
var x = 0;

for (var k in data.na)
{
    var contentId = data.na[k].contentId;
    var contentType = data.na[k].contentType;
    var key = contentType + '_' + contentId;
    var address = data.na[k].address;
    var topics = data.na[k].topic;
    var research_theme = data.na[k].research_theme;

    places[key]["na" + x]= [address, topics, research_theme];       
    x++;    
}
```

However it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'na0' of undefined 
why? I want to have na0, na1 and so on. How can I do that?

Comment: `places[key]` is undefined

Comment: Your `places` object is empty - it doesn't have any members defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
places[key]["na" + x]= [address, topics, research_theme];
```

is trying to set a `na0` property on `places[key]`, but there is no property with the name in `key` on `places` (it's a completely blank object), so `places[key]` is `undefined`, resulting in the error.

If your goal is to have `places[key]` be an object that you assign properties to, then add this above it:

```
if (!places[key]) {
    places[key] = {};
}
```

...so that if it doesn't exist yet, you create it before trying to set a property on it. (E.g., I'm assuming it's possible that `contentType + '_' + contactId` may have the same value on more than one loop iteration.)

---

But are you *sure* you want objects where sometimes they have `na0`, other times just `na1`, and other times just `na2` and so on? If you just want to create an `na` array for each `key`, you'd want to do this:

```
if (!places[key]) {
    places[key] = {na: []};
}
places[key].na.push([address, topics, research_theme]);
```

...but there I'm guessing at your ultimate goal. Just thought it was worth a note.

Comment: it does not create an unique key but. For ex number 5 has two address but it only puts to the array the latest one. Why?

Comment: @MertMetin: Looking at your code, I would expect you to get more than one (for instance, `na2` and `na7`). I added a note earlier to the end of my answer that may help.