# Getting "Cannot set property 'items' of undefined" while adding child object in JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add an array onto an object but getting "Cannot set property 'items' of undefined" error. Below is what I am trying to achieve

```
$rootScope.jobs.items = [];
$rootScope.jobs.item = {};
$rootScope.jobs.after = 0;
$rootScope.jobs.noOfRecord = 10;
$rootScope.jobs.busy = false;
$rootScope.jobs.finish = false;
```

where `$rootScope` is a valid object and set up by angularjs and its normal to add objects to it. `$rootScope` doesn't have any issues.

I have gone through the answers at [Why I get Cannot set property 'na0' of undefined error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763033/why-i-get-cannot-set-property-na0-of-undefined-error) but it's different.

Comment: Did you define `$rootScope.jobs` first? That would be why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `$rootScope.jobs` object first

```
$rootScope.jobs = { 
    items : [],
    item: {}, 
    after: 0,
    noOfRecord: 10,
    busy: false,
    finish:false
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `jobs` e.g.

```
$rootScope.jobs = {} ;
```

Comment: I think OP probably meant list of jobs.

Comment: @MuliYulzary It could be either. We don't know. Both work.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly what the error message is saying. `$rootScope.jobs` is undefined.

You are trying to add the property `items` to an undefined object.

A simple fix would be to init the `jobs` on the `$rootScope`:

```
$rootScope.jobs = {};
```